# Rejected edit on one of my posts

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Yesterday I answered [Javascript Bookmarklet to toggle Gmail Conversation View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49195033/javascript-bookmarklet-to-toggle-gmail-conversation-view). Everything was going fine, with a little of back and forth with OP to fix some bugs. Finally, the OP came to the conclusion my answer solves their issue and accepted it.

Some time after this, the OP notified me that they made an edit to my answer to improve compatibility. I'm all for compatibility, so I reviewed the edit and accepted it. I then left Stack Overflow for some time.

OP made another edit on my answer, to *"Make it a bit shorter and easier to read"* while I was away, so I wasn't able to review it in time. [Here is the result of the edit's review.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19060066) Two reviewers marked this as:

> *This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.*

thus rejecting the edit.

I really don't understand what made the reviewers think this edit was destructive in any way. The OP went out of their way to improve an already working solution. We should promote this kind of behavior, not reject it.

I will obviously approve this edit nonetheless, but before I do, I really want to know why it was rejected in the first place.

[When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) clearly states

> **Reviewing Code Edits**
>
> When in doubt, click 'Skip'. "Learn to love that Skip button."

If reviewers were doubting the goal of the edit (which is not a drastic change to the code, it's just some Strings storing), they should have skipped it, in my opinion, not rejected it.

Comment: I can see why it was rejected, but not why it was rejected as "spam or vandalism". I would probably have rejected it as "clearly conflicts with the author's intent", or possibly as "attempt to reply".

Comment: As long as the answer hasn't been edited since the suggested edit, as the author, you can override the reviewers' decision.

Comment: *reviewers should skip the review if there is any doubt* They probably didn't have any doubt.

Answer (score 13):

The edit is making drastic changes to the code in your answer. Generally this kind of edit is rejected by the community as it changes the post in a way the original poster may not have intended. There is no way for the reviewers in the queue to know what sort of understanding the editor and the author had come to with respect to the edit. Secondly, the reviewers may not have the technical knowledge to see if such a change is a genuine attempt at improvement or not. So changes in code other than formatting are often rejected.

I would have rejected as attempt to reply given that the editor could have added their own answer with the better solution.

The reviewers made the correct decision to reject the edit. You as the author of course have the right to override the community reject and accept the edit to your post.

Comment: The changes aren't drastic, though. he's only storing a string in a variable and using said variable later instead of repeating the string multiple times.

Comment: To a reviewer, it certainly looks like it's making drastic changes.

Comment: If the reviewer doesn't have the technical knowledge to review this, shouldn't he just skip the review and let someone else review it?

Comment: @Zenoo Technical knowledge is not expected from reviewers. Code changes in suggested edits are rarely a good idea.

Comment: a common language like js maybe.. but in general you cant expect it from reviewers in cases of lesser known tech or language. The edits may remain in review for a long time @Zenoo

Comment: "Edits should not change the original content of the post only improve it in terms of formatting, grammar" [citation needed]!

Comment: [When should I make edits to code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) clearly says reviewers should skip the review if there is any doubt ...

Comment: @Zenoo it also says in Donts: `Change the code logic or functionality`

Comment: @SurajRao It's not changing any of that ><

Comment: @Zenoo Yes, it is changing logic. It is fairly obvious that it is doing that.

Comment: @yivi Well I disagree, doing `var a = 'test';` or `var b = 'st';var a = 'te' + b`. Isn't changing the logic of the code.

Comment: @Zenoo It is changing the logic of the code, and it is not a matter of opinion. The end result might be the same, but the logic is clearly different (otherwise, there would no "improvement" on either case, making the while edit worthless).

Comment: @Zenoo Also, it was a horrible question to be answering anyway... You were basically spoonfeeding the code to the OP. A whole lot of noise about nothing.

Comment: @Zenoo See it like this: Your code already assumes that the + operator for strings performs a string concatenation. If I don't know anything about the language, the assumption might be problematic. If the same code edit is applied to a php question, the outcome would potentially be a complete nonsense.

Comment: But honestly, I really don't see the point of the whole discussion. If you think the edit should have been made, then just apply it. You can always make edits to your own posts.

Comment: @BDL I'm also reviewing edits myself, so the discussion here might help me review better in similar cases.

Comment: @Braiam fair enough removed it till I find it

Comment: @yivi if we define logic as "paths execution can take while executing a program" then no, the logic has not been changed. The if elses are exactly the same, the condition has indeed only been moved in a variable. If you have another definition of "logic", than maybe it was changed, but read the suggested edit carefully. It is not changing the logic, and it's not a matter of opinion. In retrospect, this was a good edit, that improves readability. It's understandable that it *was* rejected but please don't coerce OP here.

Comment: @Félix, that's a very poor definition of logic when talking about programming. Logic includes quite a bit more than the position of the "ifs and elses". Everything about a computer program is about logic. You can't add variable assignments and instructions and think you are not changing the logic of a computer program. If it was a good edit or not, it's arguable. But it was nonetheless a bad _suggested_ edit. The OP is free to accept it, but reviewers did alright in rejecting it.

Comment: I'd be happy to continue that in chat, as this seem like a deep topic, but isn't logic, at its core, the very essence of if then else? This is what it entails in most areas of life. Using a variable or a string literal has no effect on that.

Comment: Please read [the general Stack Exchange policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) and [the Stack Overflow FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code). I especially draw your attention to “**When in doubt, click 'Skip'**”. Once again, if you don't know, click “Skip”, not “Reject”.